# What do the tiny yellow RC cars next to the javelin throwing field do?

Tags: track-and-field

When they measure the distance of javelin throws during the European Athletics Championships in Amsterdam, there are small yellow remote controlled cars driving around.

Here is a *screenshot* of them.

[image: screenshot of the yellow RC cars]

What are the yellow cars used for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are [collecting the javelins (and other projectiles) for athletes](http://www.volvoxc.com/2006/08/millions-saw-mini-volvo-xc90-at-the-european-athletic-championships/):

> Over eight million TV viewers across Europe watched **the remote control 1:5 scale model Volvo XC90 collect javelins, discuses and hammers for the athletes** at the European Athletic Championships in Gothenburg last week.

*emphasis added*

Note that the article linked above is reporting on the 2006 Gothenburg event, so this practise has obviously stood a test of time!

Comment: I can add this [video from London 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzz-zKcmom0) where the mini car is working

Comment: While the shot put can use gravity-assist to roll the implements back the relatively short distance to the athletes (shot puts are generally won with distances on the close order of 21m at the pro level), the javelin/discus/hammer throws all travel much farther, necessitating such a tool.